# create table from comma separated text

Tags: mysql, sql

There are a couple of solutions to do this but my case is a bit different. 
For example, 
**Data Sample** 
Table: data

```
suid(bigint), start(bigint), end(bigint), route(text)
123, 111, 112, '1111, 1112, 1113, 1114'
123, 114, 115, '2221, 2222, 2223'
133, 121, 122, '331, 332, 333'
```

**Expected result**:
Need to create a Table: newdata

```
suid(bigint), start(bigint), end(bigint), road_seg1(int), road_seg2(int)
123, 111, 112, 1111, 1112
123, 111, 112, 1112, 1113
123, 111, 112, 1113, 1114
123, 114, 115, 2221, 2222
123, 114, 115, 2222, 2223
133, 121, 122, 331, 332
133, 121, 122, 332, 333
```

so I will need the {first, second}, {second, third}, {third, fourth}..... from route(text) 
**route(text) items can proboblaly have up to 100 items but the total number of items is random**
any help will be greatly appreciated. I am using MySql. 
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you use awk to change your file to the required format, then load it.

Answer (score 1):

If there are a finite number of such junctions, you can do this with a rather complicated query:

```
select d.suid, s.start, s.end,
       substring(substring_index(route, ', ', n.n), ', ', -1) as road_seg1,
       substring(substring_index(route, ', ', n.n+1), ', ', -1) as road_seg2
from data d cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3
     ) n
where length(replace(route, ', ', ', x')) - length(route) <= n.n;
```

The nested calls to `substring_index()` are extracting the nth and nth+1 items from the string.  The total number of items the query looks for is defined by the subquery `n` (in this case, 3 but you can add more values).  The `where` clause chooses values of `n` less than the number of items in the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what if I do not know how many items there will be in the route(text)? Will I still be able to use this??

Comment: @user3230889 . . . If there is a reasonable maximum such as 10, then you can expand `n` to use this.  If there isn't, you probably want to go to a stored procedure approach.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff  max could be about up to 100. I am not familiar with a stored approach. I'm pretty new to this. :)

Comment: @user3230889 . . . You could try extending the `n` query to 100 (lots of typing, Excel can help create the query if you don't have a numbers table already in the database).

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff... a bit lost wirh he Excel... and I ran the code but the results are different.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is the `awk` program I suggested for converting the input data:

```
BEGIN                           
  {FS=","; OFS=","}            
  {                           
    gsub(/'/,"");            
    for(i=4;i<=NF-1;i++){       
      print $1,$2,$3,$i,$(i+1) ;
      };                        
   }
```

Gives this output on your test data:

```
123, 111, 112, 1111, 1112
123, 111, 112, 1112, 1113
123, 111, 112, 1113, 1114
123, 114, 115, 2221, 2222
123, 114, 115, 2222, 2223
133, 121, 122, 331, 332
133, 121, 122, 332, 333
```

Comment: Note: depending on how you run this, you may need to replace the single quote with `\x27` or `\047`.